# Autocomplete dropdown for Asp.net

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I am working on ASP.net with javascript. I have a dropdown in a page and now it needs to be autocomplete(filter by text). I found some link for this issue but everything related to Jquery and it is not working for me.

Can any one suggest me a approach to handle my requirement. Even telerik is good for me.

Thanks in advance. 
Answers appreciated.

Thanks,
Dhinesh

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a datalist?

Try this:

```
<input list="optionsList" placeholder="-- Selecionar Marca --">
    <datalist id="optionsList" style="visibility:hidden">
        <option value="Option A">
        <option value="Option B">
        <option value="Option C">
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: No, autocomplete and filtering the data in dropdown.